# How to get user online_presence status after FQL will be deprecated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, deprecated

Currently the best (and perhaps the only) way to check if user is online on Facebook is to check his FQL **online_presence** property from **users** table. But since FQL gonna be deprecated soon (together with XMPP), it won't be possible to retrieve online_presence anymore.

Is there another way to get user online status (perhaps from Graph API)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way I know that you can get the `online_presence` from a Graph API endpoint. It's missing in the `/{user_id}` fields (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/)

IMHO, you can continue using FQL until August 7th, 2016, so I'd recommend to stick with your current solution. Maybe the Graph API is updated in the future to also return the `online_presence`.

Answer (score 0):

`online_presence` is a very old FQL query that was removed several years ago (back in v2.0). According to [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650066/requesting-facebook-friends-online-presence-through-the-graph-api) post, it is no longer possible in any way.