# Requesting Facebook friends online presence through the Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used the Facebook's FQL API to query the user's all friends online_presence but this API has been deprecated and I can not figure out how to get this information by an other way. (As I understand the chat API is also deprecated so I can not use a xmpp client)
There is a simple FQL query which I have used:

```
SELECT uid, online_presence FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY name
```

I found the friends_online_presence permission on the list of removed permissions in the new 3.0 SDK.
[(more)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/)

Is there an other way to access this data using the new API?
Thank you for any help.

(I have more than 280k downloads and hundreds of subscriptions on my app which is based on this query. Please help.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog?locale=en_GB**

> All friends_* permissions have been removed

Meaning, you can´t get any details of friends anymore in v2.0, that includes their online presence.

Also, it is not even possible anymore to check for the online presence of the authorized user:

> user_online_presence is no longer available.

TL;DR: It´s not possible in v2.0 anymore and there is no new API for it.

Comment: Yes, I have read this but I wondered to know is it definitely removed or it will be available in an other way. It means that all not official messenger apps will stop working. This will cause that a huge amount of paid apps will stop working soon and the users will request a refund.

Comment: It's not possible in any way, it is removed from the API.

Comment: it´s not THAT soon, the existing apps will still work until april 2015 so there is plenty of time to tell the users and not make them pay for stuff that will not work after the deprecation.

Comment: It was removed 8 months ago and there is another 4 until it stop working for you. 1 year is not enough?