# how to fetch on-line friends list using graph api v2.2?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I am new to facebook API and we have to migrate our project from unversioned(1.0) to 2.2. Earlier in 1.0, we were invoking http request consisting fql query to fetch friends who are on-line. Can you please help out with v2.2

Comment: So what happens if you use the FQL query you already had? Does it simply not work? Are there any errors? I assume you had a look through Facebook's API documentation?

Comment: FQL is deprecated after v2.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Requesting Facebook friends online presence through the Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650066/requesting-facebook-friends-online-presence-through-the-graph-api). Summary: It is no longer supported at present to request the online friends list / check online presence for users.